# Tensor product decomposition from Schur's lemma

Tags: tensor-calculus, representation-theory, quantum-error-correction

I was reading a paper on subsystem codes for quantum error correction:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0506023

In section IV.B, equation (16), they have arrived at a tensor decomposition of Hilbert spaces where the gauge operators (T) and the logical operators (L) act on  different tensor product spaces. The above paper arrived at the same  via Schur's Lemma.

However from what I am aware Schur's lemma says that if a non zero operator commutes with all representatives of an irreducible group representation, then it must be a multiple of identity.
We can use the contrapositive of the statement to deduce that if a non multiple of identity commutes with a representation then it must be a reducible representation.

But I am not sure how to deduce the tensor product structure from above. A direct sum structure should be implied though (by reducibilty of representation).
Is this via a different version of Schur's lemma?